# Set html tag lang attribute accordingly using flask babel

Tags: python, flask, python-babel

Looking at the docs I find no mention to this pretty basic and common need:

I want to set the `html` tag `lang` attribute according to selected locale -- without passing it explicitly every time to `render_template`, e.g.

```
<html lang="{{ lang }}">
```

Only thing coming to my mind is adding `Babel.locale_selector_func` to context, which seems overkill to me

```
babel = Babel(app)
...
@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    return dict(lang=babel.locale_selector_func)
```

and then I can do

```
<html lang="{{ lang() }}">
```

Comment: Can you not add a translation for the contents in the ‘lang’ tag? In that way the translation will be selected by the actual displayed translation!

Answer (score 1):

I do think that injecting the lang into the context is the way to go.

Only one small change I'd make myself, I'd call the function in python and just return the value in the template instead of calling the function in the template:

```
babel = Babel(app)
...
@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    return dict(lang=babel.locale_selector_func())
```

...

```
<html lang="{{ lang }}">
```

I looked through the babel source code a bit, but they are only injecting the translation functions into the template, and not the actual language. So I guess this is the *only* way to go.